# Auto space a text each 4 characters by CSS?

Tags: css, letter-spacing, word-spacing

I wanted to ask if that text can automatically change to that form when you type by CSS.

**Before** : 513031421694 // **After** : 5130 3142 1694

---

I tried these ones (letter-spacing / word-spacing), without success, and I can only touch the CSS.

Comment: In my years of writing CSS I've never seen anything like what you're asking.  What is keeping you from attaching a bit of JavaScript?

Comment: This isn't possible with CSS alone.

Comment: I don't think you can with pure css, the only thing that i know that is related is [text letter spacing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp) but that is for every character

Comment: It can't be achieved for text inputs. For regular block element, there may be hacky workarounds (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/au5m5n3j/1/), but none of them can be considered reliable. Script that creates extra markup to achieve this seems to be the best way by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly not at the moment, a JS solution is probably your only frontend option to achieve formatting across all element types.

There has been a [CSS Working Group idea](https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/content-formatting) for [data content formatting](https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/content-formatting) which would address this issue, though it seems to have had no movement or mention since 2008.

They proposed 2 new CSS rules `@decimal-format` and `number-format`.

```
@decimal-format price {
  grouping-separator: ",";
  decimal-separator : "."
}

.price {
  number-format: "###,##0.00", "price";
  /* price is actually redundant as this format would be the default */
}
```

Then a simple class would apply the formatting.

```
<span class="price">987654321</span>
```

Would display as `987,654,321.00 USD`

**But this is just an [idea](https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/content-formatting) which has not moved since 2008.**

Comment: Thanks for all reply, specially this one. I will contact the developer if they can make a move.

Comment: It's regrettable that the idea is still being proposed.